# List union that depends / selects on property values

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a class "item":

```
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Item item)
                return item.Id == Id;

            return false;
        }

        // GetHashCode omitted...
    }
```

And I have 2 lists that I need to union:

```
        var items1 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Id = 1, Price = 10 },
            new Item { Id = 2, Price = 10 },
            new Item { Id = 3, Price = 10 },
        };

        var items2 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Id = 1, Price = 10 },
            new Item { Id = 2, Price = 8 },
            new Item { Id = 4, Price = 10 },
        };
```

The union I get like this:

```
var union = items1.Union(items2).ToList();
```

But I need also the constraint that the items with the lowest price is in the union. So for example in the above lists Item.ID = 2 from "items2" must be in the union...so the result should be a list consisting of these 4 items:

- Item { Id = 1, Price = 10 }
- Item { Id = 2, Price = 8 }   // Not the one with Price = 10
- Item { Id = 3, Price = 10 }
- Item { Id = 4, Price = 10 }

Is there an elegant way of doing this in C# (preferably using Linq)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using **groupby**, like below :

```
var result = items1.Union(items2).GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                 .Select(x => new Item
                 {
                     Id = x.Key,
                     Price = x.Min(i => i.Price)
                 });
```

Comment: Very neat thanks. I didn't consider switching out the Equals with GroupBy. One thing though is that it requires me to create new Items. In the real application I might hit a performance issue doing that. Need to test...

Comment: Any way to avoid newing up Item?

Comment: You asking to avoid the new item in select statement?

Comment: Yes exactly. Btw I'm looking at MoreLinq from Nuget. Perhaps some usable gems for this particular use case. The lists are not that large, but the Item structure is...

Comment: You can remove that Item keyword there. Like .Select(x=>new {Id=x.Key, Price = x.Min(i=>i.Price)}). This makes the return type as anonymous type.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't really change the fact that I create a new Item (although that specific Item I'm after already is created and in the second list). Creating / Copying the Item is expensive in my case so that is probably not an option.